# File size limit for importing text file into postgreSQL using phpPGAdmin

Tags: php, phppgadmin

I'm still trying to import a large text file into phpPgAdmin and not succeeding.  I have changed the following fields in the php.ini file, but it didn't help.

I changed the following fields to:

```
upload_max_filesize = 3G
post_max_size = 4G
memory_limit = 5G
```

I believe the timeout default is 30 seconds (which I haven't changed), but I get error messages right away saying "No server supplied!" or "Import error: File could not be uploaded to the server".

And these are very small files compared to the 2GB text file I am trying to import.  The largest file I have been able to import is 1.6 MB.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This error was happening to me, and the solution is pretty simple (something that could easily be overlooked). This is an older post, but since it came up first on a google search I hope I can save someone some time. Restart apache and the changes should take effect. Cheers!